# Yii2 mongodb update by regex

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I'm trying to update data by regex condition. 
When I'm calling this method nothing was updated:

```
$collection->update(
    ['post_barelink' => ['$regex' => '.*shared.com' . $barelink . '$"']],
    [
        'ga_bounceRate' => isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : 0,
        'ga_avgSessionDuration' => isset($row[2]) ? $row[2] : 0,
        'ga_pageviewsPerSession' => isset($row[3]) ? $row[3] : 0,
     ]);
```

But when I'm using

```
$collection->find(['post_barelink' => ['$regex' => '.*shared.com' . $barelink . '$']])->toArray();
```

I'm getting some results from DB.

How can I set the condition for update method to get the same results like find()

Comment: use multi:true, I don't know how it's on PHP but you need it :)

Comment: Yes, thanks) but it didn't solve the main problem. Anyway, I have found the solution without using regex in update method

Answer (score 0):

use the MongoRegex class to define regex conditions

Refer- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php

```
['post_barelink' => new \MongoRegex($regexCondition)],
```

and in update function last argument can be used to set update options ex:

```
['multi'=>true,'upsert'=>false]
```